# find the Internet explorer version installed in a given ip

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, shell, networking

Is there a way to find the internet explorer version in a machine by giving its ip address, is there a script to acheive the same?

Thanks 
Jeyaprakash.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. IP is not set by the web browser but by the machine.

Answer (score 0):

No, one thing has absolutely no relation to the other.

Given you tagged your question with "javascript" I am assuming you want to achieve this on a web page, so just simply use the `navigator.userAgent` string to find out the user's browser. It should give you something like the following if it's IE:

*Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; **MSIE 9.0**; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)*